# Can I use "XP1-Distributed.ps1" to distributed installation for 3 server

Tags: sitecore

Can I use "XP1-Distributed.ps1"  to distributed installation for 3 server

It fails when create app pool in IIS

[image]

The error is:
[image]

I want confirm the "XP1-Distributed.ps1" install one role in one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because in script json file use "DnsName" to create binding website
I change DnsName to SiteName it work for me